# Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence near index for regex for url

Tags: regex

https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex
I am using the regex by @diegoperini in the above url but I am getting the following exception,

```
Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence near index 318
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3]) (?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))| (?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a- z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: why am I getting the exception? I have already tested the regex online its working! and what is the string equivalent of the regex in java?

Comment: I have used the tool as per the suggestions but it fails during compliation and gives me the above exception